# How to enable/disable the commandbutton

Tags: visualforce

How to disable the button if the list size is 0 or null ? i have `selectedcontacts` is a collection of list.

```
<apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" title="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}">   
        <div align="center" style="padding:15px;" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}">            
              <apex:commandbutton value="Add to Work Order!"/>
        </div>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,true,false)}">
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably handle that with Javascript and CSS. I don't know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have an attribute called `disabled` in apex:commandButton. You can use it like

```
<apex:commandButton disabled="{!If(selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.size > 0,false, true)}">
```

Here if the selectedContacts size is greater than 0, command button will be enabled as the formula will become disabled=false.

Hope it helps